# Array merge on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Either I'm blind or I can't find this problem anywhere here on SO.
Yesterday I had a problem with merging arrays, which I could fix with the help of SO. Today I have, again, a problem with merging arrays, but this time it's with multidimensional Arrays.

I have an array `$usergroup['groups']` and an array `$usergroup['lang']`

`$usergroup['groups']` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [2] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [deleted] => 0
        )

)
```

And `$usergroup['lang']` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [id_usergroup] => 1
            [name] => Administratoren
            [id_lang] => 1
        )

    [1] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [id_usergroup] => 2
            [name] => Benutzer
            [id_lang] => 1
        )

    [2] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [id_usergroup] => 3
            [name] => Gäste
            [id_lang] => 1
        )

)
```

I want my merged array to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id_usergroup] => 1
            [name] => Administratoren
            [id_lang] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [id_usergroup] => 2
            [name] => Benutzer
            [id_lang] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
        )

    [2] => Usergroup_Model Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [id_usergroup] => 3
            [name] => Gäste
            [id_lang] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
        )

)
```

[What have I tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

I've tried several merging functions (`array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()`) of PHP, the closest result I got was, that the second Array (`['lang']`) overwrote the first Array (`['groups']`). To fix that, I tried to remove the empty values on the `lang` Array (which is always `id`). But that does not fix it. The code - at the moment - looks like this:

```
public static function getAll()
{
  $usergroup['groups'] = self::find();
  $usergroup['lang'] = self::findInTable(array(
    'id_lang' => Language_Model::getDefaultLanguage()
  ), self::dbTranslationTable);
  foreach ($usergroup as $ug) {
    $ug = array_filter($ug, function($val) {
      return $val != '';
    });
  }
  return array_merge($ug);
}
```

The array_merge() on the return command doesn't seem to do anything at all, so I'm probably not gathering the data correctly or I mess something up with the Arrays (forgetting to add [], or I don't know...). I kinda miss the forest for the trees here.

Any suggestions in which direction I could go?

**Edit:** With the code provided by Pé de Leão I was able to solve the problem. My function now looks like this:

```
public static function getAll()
{
  $usergroup['groups'] = self::find();
  $usergroup['lang'] = self::findInTable(array(
    'id_lang' => Language_Model::getDefaultLanguage()
  ), self::dbTranslationTable);
  $out = array();
  foreach ($usergroup['groups'] as $key => $value) {
    $out[] = (object) array_merge((array) $usergroup['lang'][$key], (array) $value);
  }
  return $out;
}
```

And the result is exactly how I wanted it!

Comment: Use `array_merge_recursive` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: I did, but the result is the same. `lang` overrides `groups`

Comment: If you have sum arrays, try this `$resultArray = $usergroup['groups'] + $usergroup['lang']`

Comment: How do I have to understand this? I just tried `return $usergroup['groups'] + $usergroup['lang']` and now the `lang` array is completely missing.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Arr#merge It depends on Arr::is_assoc which can be found on the same page.

Comment: I'm gonna have a look on this, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $out[] = (object)array_merge((array)$arr2[$key], (array)$value);
}
print_r($out)
```

Comment: can u pls explain why did u used (array) in between array_merge and $arr2[$key].
or a reference in detail would be helpful

Comment: @DhruvThakkar That's [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to ensure that the parameter is interpreted as an array.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its not the smartest but you can try it like this, too:

```
public static function getAll()
{
  $groups = self::find();
  $lang = self::findInTable(array(
    'id_lang' => Language_Model::getDefaultLanguage()
  ), self::dbTranslationTable);

  $n = array();
  foreach($groups as $g) {
      $id = $g['id'];
      $n[$id] = $g;
  }

  foreach($lang as $a) {
      $id = $a['id_usergroup'];
      if(!isset($n[$id])){ $n[$id] = array(); }
      $n[$id]['id_usergroup'] = $a['id_usergroup'];
      $n[$id]['name'] = $a['name'];
      $n[$id]['id_lang'] = $a['id_lang'];
  }

  return $n;
}
```

the key of the returned array will be the id of the group in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I have never array_merge() with objects before.  I suspect you would need to have classes like UNION for it to work (i.e. public data).

- Assertion: this is your data structure and it won't change much.
- Assertion: if you had provided var_export() output rather than print_r() in the samples at the top, I could have executed the following (to test it)...
- It would be better to use a more specific class in the last used cast statement, but I don't know your class hierarchy ~ Usergroup_Model?
- This answer ignore anything to do with getDefaultLanguage() as that wasn't part of the question.

  ```
  $ITEMS=count($usergroup['groups']);
  $out=array();
  for($i=0; $i<$ITEMS; $i++) {
      if(isset($usergroup['lang'][$i])) {
          $out[]=(object)array_merge((array)$usergroup['groups'][$i], (array)$usergroup['lang'][$i]);
      } else {
          $out[]=$usergroup['groups'][$i];
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($array1) >= count($array2)){
    $arr1 = $array1;
    $arr2 = $array2;
}else{
    $arr1 = $array2;
    $arr2 = $array1;
}

$out = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($arr2[$key])){
        $out[] = array_merge((array)$arr2[$key], (array)$value);
    }else{
        $out[] = (array)$value;
    }
}

pr($out);
```