# combining-two-mysql-queries-into-one-json-array-in-php

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
  $sql1 =  "select distinct date, count(id) from windows where start_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-31' and (start_date!='0000-00-00') group by date";
  $sql2 =   "select distinct date, count(id) from AIX where start_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-31' and (start_date!='0000-00-00') group by date";
```

I have these two queries which return output in the form of (date,ID). What i want is to merge these two tables so that i get result in one array as (date,ID1,ID2) where ID1 is of 'windows' table and ID2 is of 'AIX' table and according to date they must print the ID's. I tried using "join" but that didn't work. 
I used array_merge() in php to combine the results to one json array but that didn't work either. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: try to use `array_combine()`

Comment: may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850353/array-merge-on-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to combine aggregations from two different tables, I think you will have to aggregate separately first and then somehow combine the results.  In the query below, I aggregate over your two tables in subqueries and then join them on the date.  This should work assuming that both tables have all dates present and have the same dates.

```
SELECT
    t1.date,
    t2.cnt1,
    t3.cnt2
FROM calendar t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(id) AS cnt1
    FROM windows
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-10-31'
    GROUP BY date
) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT date, COUNT(id) AS cnt2
    FROM AIX
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-10-31'
    GROUP BY date
) t3
    ON t1.date = t3.date;
```

As I mentioned above, if either table be completely missing a date, then you will have to do more work.  In this case, you could resort to joining with a calendar table to include the missing dates.

**Edit:**

I have updated the query slightly to use a calendar table.  To make this query work, just define a table `calendar` with a `date` column containing the full range of dates to cover both of your tables.

Comment: Thank you Tim, but the problem is both the tables have different dates and missing dates. How do we join with a calendar table? can you elaborate?