# add item array in a exist array php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to add an item array in a exist array. When i try to add i get something like this, using `array_push`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [totalp] => 3.26
            [mes] => Novembro
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [totalp] => 2.66
            [mes] => Dezembro
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [bonus] => 2.6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [bonus] => 4.16
                )

        )

)
```

but i need this.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [totalp] => 3.26
            [mes] => Novembro
            [bonus] => 2.6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [totalp] => 2.66
            [mes] => Dezembro
            [bonus] => 4.16
        )   )
```

follow my code.

```
$arrRows = array();
while ($dados = $resultp ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$arrRows[] = $dados;//getting totalp and mes here
}

$arrRows1 = array();
while ($dados = $resultb ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $arrRows1[]=$dados; //getting bonus here
     }

array_push($arrRows,$arrRows1); // first example, but i dont need this way.
print_r($arrRows);
```

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array_map

```
$res = array_map('array_merge', $arrRows, $arrRows1);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/928995)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$newdata =  array (
      0 => array('totalp'=>'3.26','mes' => 'Novembro'),
      1 => array('totalp'=>'2.66','mes' => 'Dezembro')

    );



foreach($newdata as $key => $value){
    $newdata[$key]['Bonus'] = "12";
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newdata);
```

Check it On **[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/928989)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that add bonus in multidimensional array

```
<?php

    $array = array(
      array(
        "totalp" => "3.26",
        "mes" => "Novembro"
      ),
      array(
        "totalp" => "3.26",
        "mes" => "Novembro"
      )
    );


    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) { 
        $array[$i]['bonus'] = "2.2"; // here is you can get output from another array or variable
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

[See Output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f947645b07d7dc2dc7417ddfcfd2cf383ce3767)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
foreach($arrRows as $key=>$row){
    $arrRows[$key]['bonus'] = $arrRows1[$key]['bonus'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrRows);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array merge like below code snippet:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arrRows as $key => $value){
    $out[] = array_merge((array)$arrRows1[$key], (array)$value);
}
print_r($out);
```

You can check this url for reference: [Array merge on multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850353/array-merge-on-multidimensional-array)