# Combine multiple arrays into one with same date

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a project where I need to combine multiple arrays to one who has the same date. Let me show you an example

```
["first"]=>
{
    [0]=>
    {
      ["date"]=> "Jun 14",
      ["hhp_signed"]=> "0"
    }
}

["second"]=>
 {
    [0]=>
    {
      ["date"]=> "Jun 14",
      ["coupon_purchased"]=> 0
    }
 }

["third"]=>
{
    [0]=>
    {
      ["date"]=> "Jun 14",
      ["user_subscription"]=> "0"
    }
}
```

Here is the expected result

```
["final"] => {
    [0] => {
    ["date"]=> "Jun 14",
    ["hhp_signed"] => 0,
    ["coupon_purchased"] => 0,
    ["user_subscription"] => 0
    }
    [1] => {
    ["date"]=> "Jun 15",
    ["hhp_signed"] => 2,
    ["coupon_purchased"] => 5,
    ["user_subscription"] => 0
    }
 }
```

Currently I am writing values of three arrays but there could be more than three arrays may be 7 or 8

I have tried this function but it only works for two arrays, in my case, there would be more than two.

```
function combo($array1, $array2) {
    $output = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    foreach ( $arrayAB as $value ) {
      $id = $value['date'];
      if ( !isset($output[$id]) ) {
        $output[$id] = array();
      }
      $output[$id] = array_merge($output[$id], $value);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I really thanks you for your efforts

Comment: To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: This is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850353/array-merge-on-multidimensional-array

Comment: Hi Riggs. It's really an unprofessional way to ask something. I just need a function to combine arrays, I want not asking you to write code for me.

Comment: How else are we supposed to answer a question like this without writing code for you. If you gave it a try we would be more than willing to help fix your attempt

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, I edited my question to show you function I am using. Sometimes a developer doesn't know where to start so he needs some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `array_merge` function.

Example:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($original_array as $value)
{
     $final[$value['date']] = array_merge($final, $value);
}
$final['final'] = $final;  // like your example
```

Comment: Hi @pablorsk. Thanks for the answer. I just want to know how can I get the date from my array. I have the structure like this
`["first"]=>
{
    [0]=>
    {
      ["date"]=> "Jun 14",
      ["hhp_signed"]=> "0"
    }
}`
So you can see that date key have parent key **first**. Thank you again.

Comment: just do `$date = $array['first'][0]['date'];`. This is ok for you?