# marge two php array with folloging condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two array students and marks . Need a output array like marks_sheet.Delete all data which is not present in marks array and insert a new field marks.
// name of this array **students**

```
Array    
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userId] => user1
                [name] => Suman Mandal
                [age] => 20    

            )
        [1] => Array
            (

                [userId] => user2
                [name] => Amit Halder
                [age] => 30

            )
        [2] => Array
            (

                [userId] => user3
                [name] => Asif Rahman
                [age] => 25

            )
        [3] => Array
            (

                [userId] => user4
                [name] => Gopal Ghosh
                [age] => 21

            )
    )
```

// name of this array **marks**

```
 Array   
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userId] => user1 
                [marks]=>80 

            )
        [1] => Array
            (

                [userId] => user3  
                [marks]=>90          
            )

    )
```

I need a output like this:
// name of this array **marks_sheet**

```
 Array   
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userId] => user1 
                [name] => Suman Mandal
                [age] => 20
                [marks]=>80 

            )
        [1] => Array
            (

                [userId] => user3  
                [name] => Asif Rahman
                [age] => 25
                [marks]=>90          
            )

    )
```

I have a little knowledge on php. May be this is so easy but I am feeling hard to solve it... please help me

Comment: What has this got to do with sql?

Comment: @Strawberry The OP is confused and is showing the result sets in PHP rather than tabular MySQL data, which is what we really want to see.

Comment: sorry...friends.. my question have little mistake which i have checked

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think not

Comment: Just check this link <br/><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850353/array-merge-on-multidimensional-array"> Check this link you must get you solution</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two multidimensional arrays on specific key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669554/merging-two-multidimensional-arrays-on-specific-key)

Comment: @SumanMandal Why do you not want to get result right  by mysql? show queries yo use now

Comment: @mukeshkumar if you believe the question is a duplicate of another, please use the `close` link at the bottom of the question. When you do it will automatically create a comment with the link to the question. Please do not repeatedly comment a link to the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_replace_recusrive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) on the `userId` indexed arrays.

First use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to index the arrays by the `userId`.

Then use `array_replace_recursive` to merge the values in the arrays and retain the key indexes of both array sets.

Lastly use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to only return the array values from the `$marks` array.

### Example https://3v4l.org/adrYV

```
$students = array_column($students, null, 'userId');
$marks = array_column($marks, null, 'userId');
$marks_sheet = array_intersect_key(array_replace_recursive($students, $marks), $marks);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [user1] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user1
            [name] => Suman Mandal
            [age] => 20
            [marks] => 80
        )

    [user3] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user3
            [name] => Asif Rahman
            [age] => 25
            [marks] => 90
        )

)
```

If you need the end result to not be indexed by `userId` you can use `array_values`, which will reindex the array.

```
$marks_sheet = array_values(
    array_intersect_key(array_replace_recursive($students, $marks), $marks)
);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user1
            [name] => Suman Mandal
            [age] => 20
            [marks] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user3
            [name] => Asif Rahman
            [age] => 25
            [marks] => 90
        )

)
```

---

Alternatively you can iterate over the marks and students to build your marks_sheet array.

### Example https://3v4l.org/Xmg3a

```
$marks_sheet = [];
foreach ($marks as $mark) {
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        if ($student['userId'] === $mark['userId']) {
            $mark_sheet = $student;
            foreach ($mark as $key => $value) {
                $mark_sheet[$key] = $value;
            }
            $marks_sheet[] = $mark_sheet;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user1
            [name] => Suman Mandal
            [age] => 20
            [marks] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userId] => user3
            [name] => Asif Rahman
            [age] => 25
            [marks] => 90
        )

)
```

Comment: thank you...dear.. You have solved my problem..Love you..@fyrye