# merge two equal structural multi-arrays with different data

Tags: php, arrays

i can't believe that i can't find a solution to this seemingly simple problem, and i tried everything.

i have two multi arrays:

the first one:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 1
                    [id_note] => 1
                    [surname] => Rawson
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 
                    [id_note] => 18
                    [surname] => Vallejo
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [available] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

the second one has the exact same structure, but with new data:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [final_approved] => 1
                    [final_id_note] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [final_approved] => 
                    [final_id_note] => 19
                )

        )

)
```

what i need mergin both multi-arrays is this result:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 1
                    [id_note] => 1
                    [surname] => Rawson
                    [final_approved] => 1
                    [final_id_note] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 
                    [id_note] => 18
                    [surname] => Vallejo
                    [final_approved] => 
                    [final_id_note] => 19
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [available] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

but i can't get this result with any common php function:

array_merge:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 1
                    [id_note] => 1
                    [surname] => Rawson
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 
                    [id_note] => 18
                    [surname] => Vallejo
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [available] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [final_approved] => 1
                    [final_id_note] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [final_approved] => 
                    [final_id_note] => 19
                )

        )

)
```

it replaces with new indexes.

array_push:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 1
                    [id_note] => 1
                    [surname] => Rawson
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [approved] => 
                    [id_note] => 18
                    [surname] => Vallejo
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [available] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [final_approved] => 1
                            [final_id_note] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [final_approved] => 
                            [final_id_note] => 19
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

it literally pushes in with the second array with new indexes, which is correct of course lol

i guess that the answer is pretty simple, but i already googled and try everything that my newbie ability can.

can anyone give me some advice?

thanks!

Comment: i understand what you mean, and i'm implementing that, but there is no native array function that already do this without the loop?

Comment: It seems like `foreach` is the way to go, and there's no specific function for multidimensional arrays - [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850353/array-merge-on-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are recursive array functions in PHP. [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive), despite the promising name, will not work here, as it will *reindex the numeric keys* and add overlapping the data to the end.

However, there is [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/array_replace_recursive) that does exactly what you want when you have a multidimensional array with significant keys. Here's your data (in a usable format!):

```
// The base data:

$a_one = [
  3 => [
    1 => [
      'approved' => 1,
      'id_note' => 1,
      'surname' => 'Rawson',
    ],
    2 => [
      'approved' => 0,
      'id_note' => 18,
      'surname' => 'Vallejo',
    ],
  ],
  4 => [
    1 => [
      'school_id' => 1,
    ],
    2 => [
      'available' => 1,
    ],
  ],
];

// Data to be added by matching keys:

$a_two = [
  3 => [
    1 => [
      'final_approved' => 1,
      'final_id_note' => 1,
    ],
    2 => [
      'final_approved' => 0,
      'final_id_note' => 19,
    ],
  ],
];
```

Then let's mash them together:

```
$merged = array_replace_recursive($a_one, $a_two);
```

This results in the following "merged" array:

```
[
  3 => [
    1 => [
      'approved' => 1,
      'id_note' => 1,
      'surname' => 'Rawson',
      'final_approved' => 1,
      'final_id_note' => 1,
    ],
    2 => [
      'approved' => 0,
      'id_note' => 18,
      'surname' => 'Vallejo',
      'final_approved' => 0,
      'final_id_note' => 19,
    ],
  ],
  4 => [
    1 => [
      'school_id' => 1,
    ],
    2 => [
      'available' => 1,
    ],
  ],
]
```

In summary, the way this function behaves (from the manual, numbering added):

> 1. If a key from the first array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value from the second array.
> 2. If the key exists in the second array, and not the first, it will be created in the first array.
> 3. If a key only exists in the first array, it will be left as is.

Or in a more compact statement:

```
key: scalar EXISTS in A, B => REPLACE from B to A
key: scalar EXISTS in B => CREATE in A
key: scalar EXISTS in A => LEAVE in A
```

Again, the manual says:

> When the value in the first array is scalar, it will be replaced by the value in the second array, may it be scalar or array. *When the value in the first array and the second array are both arrays*, array_replace_recursive() will replace their respective value recursively.

What's important to note here is that *array members with matching keys, that are arrays, will not be "replaced" in full*. The "replacement" only applies to the *final scalar values* or "leaves" of the array (per the logic above). The arrays will be "merged", ie. *non-matching keys with scalar values will be combined* within each "final array" (or "leafy array" for lack of a better term).

N.B. If you're using this function to "merge" more complex arrays, you'll want to double-check that the outcome matches your expectations. I can't remember off the top of my head all the "quirks" that exist in using this function, but I assure you they are there... don't assume that it will create a seamless union of any and all datasets you may throw at it.